# Улучшение копирования файлов

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

```
 public static void CopyLaunchFiles()
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(LaunchPath(), "*.", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        var files2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(LaunchPath() + classT.Config, "*.ini", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        try
        {
            foreach (var Load in files)
            {
                File.Copy(Load, classT.Str2 + Path.GetFileName(Load));
            }
            foreach (var fi in files2)
            {
                File.Copy(fi, classT.Str2 + classT.Config + Path.GetFileName(fi));
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

---

Нужно ли использовать `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>` для улучшения производительности?
Что лучше подойдёт для копирования/удаления файлов?

Можно ли В `Directory.EnumeratFiles` присвоить 2 формата(паттерна)?

И в каком случае `Task` лучше не использовать?

---

Вообще логику хочу такую сделать:

1 - Находим по маске файлы во всех папках ( нужной директории)

2 - Копируем нужные файлы по маске в нужные нам директории)

Как бы реализовать копирование по маске "*." в одну папку, а "*.ini" в другую!

Comment: Вроде нашёл решение для 2 форматов, но нужен Ваш совет, использование `Union`?

Comment: 1) При Union будет 2 прохода сканирования папки. 2) Task.Factory.StartNew прироста не даст - на уровне драйвера запросы к диску все равно станут в очередь.

Comment: @vitidev,Да 2 прохода,а можно ли при копирование указать  например `"*."` файлы копировать в одну папку, а `"*.ini"` в другую?

Comment: Делаете один проход и проверяете каждое имя файла на соответствие маске. По результату разное поведение. fnmatch в шарпе похоже нет, поэтому придется взять кастомную реализацию например тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652037/how-do-i-check-if-a-filename-matches-a-wildcard-pattern.

Comment: Метод `File.Copy` синхронный. То есть пока он выполняется, поток занят. Поэтому в GUI потоке вызываеть его не следует. Лучше всего использовать асинхронность. Советую посмотреть небольшую книгу Тауба [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) - в конце приведён шикарный пример async копирования с отменой, прогрессом и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это хорошо) Вот только я не знаю как прикрутить его к моему методу.